# How can I create a while loop that runs all the time but doesn't interfere with the order that the code runs in?

Tags: python, loops

I'm making a text adventure game in Python to get myself started, as I am not that good at Python yet. I have tried to implement a set of health rules:

```
while True:
   if health == maxHealth:
       playerAtMaxHealth = True;
   elif health > maxHealth:
       health = maxHealth;
   elif health < 0:
       health = 0
   elif health == 0:
       playerDead = True;
```

Here is it with the rest of my code:

```
def startUp():
  StartPRINT("""╔═══╗
║╔══╝
║╚══╦══╦══╦══╦══╦══╗
║╔══╣══╣╔═╣╔╗║╔╗║║═╣
║╚══╬══║╚═╣╔╗║╚╝║║═╣
╚═══╩══╩══╩╝╚╣╔═╩══╝
─────────────║║
─────────────╚╝ \n""")
  global gold
  global health
  global inventory
  global berryCollected;
  global maxHealth;
  global playerAtMaxHealth;
  global playerDead
  berryCollected = False;
  playerAtMaxHealth = True;
  playerDead = False
  gold = 0
  health = 30
  maxHealth = 30
  inventory = []
  time.sleep(2)
  while True:
    if health == maxHealth:
      playerAtMaxHealth = True;
    elif health > maxHealth:
      health = maxHealth;
    elif health < 0:
      health = 0
    elif health == 0:
      playerDead = True;
  forest()
```

Basically what happens is that it prints out the start text, but then it just gets stuck in the while loop and doesn't move onto forest().

Comment: What did you imagine *would* end the loop?

Comment: Why do you have a loop?  Are you looking for multi-threading perhaps?  https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_multithreading.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if you have considered this yet, but it might be better for you to do this in an object orientated way. So, have the hero or the player as the class and his attributes being gold, health.etc. Then you can easily have a function that you can run after a fight or interaction, to check to see if the player is alive or not

Answer (score 0):

Dont use while true to cover the health rules.
So if you want checking the health of the player is like this..
While true 
     Forest() // maybe some fight with monster
     //health checking goes here...

It will do health check after some action in the forest....
If you wrote like yours it only get stuck in the health checking

Answer (score 0):

You can simply wrap your while loop inside a thread. Then start the thread and it will not change the other structure of your code. 
Creating threads in Python are extremely easy. You need to import `threading`
Then you can create a thread using `threading.Thread()` function
You can create as many threads as you want and you can simply start them using `start()` function. And they all will execute without interfering your code.

For more details on python thread refer to this [threading example of python](https://www.simplifiedpython.net/python-threading-example/).